# How do i declare my class so i can access like this

Tags: python, python-3.x, micropython, bbc-microbit

In micropython there is a module neopixel to interact with ws2812 addressable LEDs an example code is

```
from microbit import *
import neopixel

pixel = neopixel.NeoPixel(pin0, 64)

pixel[0] = (255, 0, 0)
pixel.show()
```

This declares 64 leds controlled by pin0, sets the first one to red and updates the led array.

How do i declare a class so i can just assign values like the line `pixel[0] = (255, 0,  0)` ?

Answer (score 2):

Your class needs to implement the `__setitem__` method.

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__setitem__):

> object.__getitem__(self, key)
>
> Called to implement evaluation of
>   self[key]. For sequence types, the accepted keys should be integers
>   and slice objects. Note that the special interpretation of negative
>   indexes (if the class wishes to emulate a sequence type) is up to the
>   __getitem__() method. If key is of an inappropriate type, TypeError may be raised; if of a value outside the set of indexes for the
>   sequence (after any special interpretation of negative values),
>   IndexError should be raised. For mapping types, if key is missing (not
>   in the container), KeyError should be raised.
>
> Note: for loops expect that an IndexError will be raised for illegal
>   indexes to allow proper detection of the end of the sequence.
>
> object.__setitem__(self, key, value)
>
> Called to implement assignment to
>   self[key]. Same note as for __getitem__(). This should only be
>   implemented for mappings if the objects support changes to the values
>   for keys, or if new keys can be added, or for sequences if elements
>   can be replaced. The same exceptions should be raised for improper key
>   values as for the __getitem__() method.

Answer (score 2):

Although the `__setitem__` is correct, adding getter and setter is quite recurrent in coding.

I would personaly recommend using attr : http://www.attrs.org/en/stable/examples.html

This enables tons of magic , and setter are included in the functionnalities.

After `pip install attrs`

```
import attr
@attr.s
class dummy():
    x= attr.ib()
test = dummy ([0])
test.x[0] = 2
test
```

Comment: I think the asker is using MicroPython, in which case (I think) `attrs` is not readily available. [This](https://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/reference/packages.html) and [this](https://forum.micropython.org/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=2412&p=14048) might be relevant.